# Precompiled assets not loading in rails app deployed to AWS elastic beanstalk

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

this is a question that pertains to deployment of rails application on AWS elastic beanstalk. When I type `eb logs` in console, I get the following error under `/var/log/nginx/error.log`:-

```
2017/06/04 06:02:08 [error] 31759#0:
*1 open()"/var/app/current/public/assets/trumbowyg.min.css" failed
(2: No such file or directory), client: 172.31.79.121, server: _, 
request: "GET /assets/trumbowyg.min.css HTTP/1.1",
host: "kanttly-dev.kfzi8ynhke.us-east-1.elasticbeanstalk.com", 
referrer: "http://kanttly-dev.kfzi8ynhke.us-east1.elasticbeanstalk.com/"
```

However, when I `eb ssh` and `cd /var/app/current/public/assets/ && ls`, I can see the precompiled files in the directory.

`trumbowyg.min-65157a3a7fa7c31aa4e2b9e7036c1e389339f4f7964eece797770708df9d2ca1.css`

I would be glad if there were anyone who can explain to me what the problem is since the asset(trumbowyg.min.css) is already pre-compiled and how I can load the precompiled asset. Thank you!

Comment: Maybe stupid, but is the file included in `assets.rb`?

Comment: Hi yes i added the command to precompile under assets.rb
`Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( trumbowyg.min.css )`

Comment: How are you loading the css file in your application? Are you using the `asset_path` helper?

Comment: Hey turns out i forgot to include the gem yui-compressor to compress css. In production.rb, I need to include the following code too:-

`config.assets.css_compressor = :yui`